# Kotlin: mutable map of mutable list won't update the list

Tags: kotlin

(Kotlin newbie here) I have a text file with rows that look like these:

```
1-1-1
1-1-2
1-1-3
2-1-1
2-1-2
etc.
```

I have to transform these data to a map where the key is the first 2 elements and the value is a list of the third elements that that match the key. For example, the above records will transform into this JSON:

```
1-1: [1, 2, 3]
2-1: [1, 2]
etc.
```

I'm unable to increment the list. Here's a simplified version, I get stuck on the "else":

```
fun main () {
    val l1 = mutableListOf("1-1-1", "1-1-2", "1-1-3", "2-1-1", "2-1-2")
    val m = mutableMapOf<String, List<Int>>()
    for (e in l1) {
        val c = e.split("-")
        val key = "${c[0]}-${c[1]}"
        if (m[key] == null) m[key] = listOf(c[2].toInt())
        else println("How do I append to the list?")
    }
    println(m)
}
```

Output:

```
{1-1=[1], 2-1=[1]}
```

But I want:

```
{1-1=[1, 2, 3], 2-1=[1, 2]}
```

Thank you (comments about idiomatic form are welcome!)

Comment: The answer below is correct, but as for what you are missing: Your List types are switched, l1 should be the read-only List (listOf), and the second one, the value in the map, should MutableList<Int>. You can append with the + operator, fwiw you can also do that with your current List, but that's inefficient as it will create a new one.

Answer (score 6):

If we continue to follow your strategy, what you need is for the value type to be a MutableList. Then you can add to the existing MutableList when there's already an existing list for that key:

```
fun main() {
    val l1 = mutableListOf("1-1-1", "1-1-2", "1-1-3", "2-1-1", "2-1-2")
    val m = mutableMapOf<String, MutableList<Int>>()
    for (e in l1) {
        val c = e.split("-")
        val key = "${c[0]}-${c[1]}"
        if (m[key] == null) m[key] = mutableListOf(c[2].toInt())
        else m[key]!!.add(c[2].toInt())
    }
    println(m)
}
```

This can be more natural using `getOrPut()`. It returns the existing MutableList or creates one and puts it in the map if it's missing. Then we don't have to deal with if/else, and can simply add the new item to the list.

```
fun main() {
    val l1 = mutableListOf("1-1-1", "1-1-2", "1-1-3", "2-1-1", "2-1-2")
    val m = mutableMapOf<String, MutableList<Int>>()
    for (e in l1) {
        val c = e.split("-")
        val key = "${c[0]}-${c[1]}"
        m.getOrPut(key, ::mutableListOf).add(c[2].toInt())
    }
    println(m)
}
```

But we can use the `map` and `groupBy` functions to create it more simply:

```
val m = l1.map { it.split("-") }
    .groupBy(
        { "${it[0]}-${it[1]}" }, // keys
        { it[2].toInt() } // values
    )
```

Comment: Thank you for the thorough and educational reply! The .groupby is stunningly beautiful.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve your desired output with a single call to `groupBy` of the Kotlin standard library.

```kotlin
val input = listOf("1-1-1", "1-1-2", "1-1-3", "2-1-1", "2-1-2")

val result = input.groupBy(
    { it.substringBeforeLast("-") }, // extract key from item
    { it.substringAfterLast("-").toInt() }  // extract value from item
)
```

The first lambda function extracts the key to group by of every list item. The second lambda function provides the value to use for each list item.

Answer (score 3):

You can also do it by first mapping your values to `Pair`s and then group them as follows:

```kotlin
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val input = listOf("1-1-1", "1-1-2", "1-1-3", "2-1-1", "2-1-2")

    val result = input.map {
        val values = it.split("-")
        "${values[0]}-${values[1]}" to values[2]
    }.groupBy ({ it.first }) { it.second }

    println(result)
}
```